# Is it possible to have a non-full screen modal with a header?

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I'm trying to replicate a navigation pattern that has a non-full screen modal slide up from the bottom and then have its own stack navigation header (and stack) in that modal. Is this at all possible with vanilla react-navigation? I can't see how to move the header down like that.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

See `ModalPresentationIOS` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#transitionpresets

```js
import { TransitionPresets } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// ...

<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Home"
  screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => ({
    headerShown: false,
    gestureEnabled: true,
    cardOverlayEnabled: true,
    headerStatusBarHeight:
      navigation.dangerouslyGetState().routes.indexOf(route) > 0
        ? 0
        : undefined,
    ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS,
  })}
  mode="modal"
>
  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```